# change color arrow icon react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

hi how to change color of arrow icon in react-select
in mouse over in google chrome, I find CSS variable but I cant change color.
this value of CSS css-tlfecz-indicatorContainer.
in my `customStyles` I wrote this line but not working:

```
  indicatorContainer:base =>({
        ...base,
       color:'#000000'
     }),
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

this is my component I use react-select

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
export default function DropDown(props) {
  const customStyles = {
    control: (base, state) => ({
      ...base,
      background: "#59c5b8",
      borderRadius: 0,

    }),
    menu: base => ({
      ...base,
      // override border radius to match the box
      borderRadius: 20,
      // kill the gap
      marginTop: 0,

    }),
    menuList: base => ({
      ...base,
      // kill the white space on first and last option
      padding: 0
    }),
    indicatorSeparator: base => ({
      ...base,
      display: 'none'
    }),
    myDropDown__indicator: base => ({
      ...base,
      '&.myDropDown__dropdown-indicator': {
        '&.indicatorContainer': {
          color: '#000000'
        }
      }

    }),
    '&.indicatorContainer': {
      color: '#000000'
    }
  };


  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = selectedOption => {

    setSelectedOption(selectedOption)

    props.parentCallBack(selectedOption)
  };
  return (
    <Select


      isSearchable={false}
      styles={customStyles}
      isOptionDisabled={true}
      defaultValue={props.options[0]}
      isRtl={true}
      onChange={handleChange}
      options={props.options}
      classNamePrefix='myDropDown'
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Which version of react-select are you using?

Comment: @UtkarshPramodGupta v3.0.8

Comment: Show us your code where you have implemented React-Select.

Comment: @UtkarshPramodGupta thanks for helping update my question

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use `customStyles` and declare a new colour for `dropdownIndicator` element:

```
const customStyles = {
  dropdownIndicator: base => ({
    ...base,
    color: "red" // Custom colour
  })
};
```

[Here](https://react-select.com/styles) you can find the list of all the elements and [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-colour-icon-dropdown-6wqdk) a live example.

Comment: This appears to only work for react-select v3. For v4 and newer see the answer below from Michal Kurowski.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I did it in version `4.3.1`

```
const style = {
  dropdownIndicator: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
    "svg": {
      fill: "red"
    }
  }),
}

return (
  <Select options={renderOptions()} styles={style} />
);
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 2):

This should help:

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

export default function DropDown(props) {
  const customStyles = {
    indicatorsContainer: () => ({
      '.myDropDown': {
        '&__dropdown-indicator': {
          color: 'red' // <--- Color of your choice
        }
      }
    })
  };

  return (
    <Select
      styles={customStyles}
      classNamePrefix='myDropDown'
    />
  );
}
```

**PS Removed non-related code for better understanding. :)**

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of the indicators when the control component is focused:

```js
dropdownIndicator: (styles, state) => ({
  ...styles,
  color: state.isFocused ? "hsl(0, 0 , 0, 80%)" : "hsl(0, 0 , 0, 60%)",
}),
```